# Mixing http and https in RestKit

Tags: iphone, ssl, restkit

I have an [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)-enabled app which makes HTTP GET calls and should make HTTPS POST calls, to protect user data that otherwise would get sent unencrypted. As far as I know, it's possible to set the RestKit framework to either use unencrypted HTTP or SSL-encrypted HTTPS for the entire app by simply **setting the base URL to the desired url**.

In my case I need to have both. How can I switch between HTTP and HTTPS in RestKit? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use two instances of the `RKObjectManager` - one for the HTTP GET calls and one for the HTTPS POST calls. Keep in mind to call each manager with the given name and not using `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` any more because it's set to the first initialized `RKObjectManager`.

As an alternative you can set the Base URL of the given `RKObjectManager` before each GET/POST call.

Comment: I only have one POST right now that needs the HTTPS and because of that and for simplicity I implemented your second solution which works quite well. To be precise, I set the HTTPS base URL right before the POST, then I do the post and after that I set the base URL back to the HTTP one. But you wrote about some problems. Can you elaborate a bit  more about what problems could arise?

Comment: Just wasn't sure enough if changing the base url could somehow result to problems with the routing path for your get calls. Glad to hear that setting the base url right before the operation works well!

Answer (score 0):

I use method swizzling to solve this problem, because [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) uses [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to do http related things, and `AFNetworking` uses

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method path:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

to generate request object. In my implementation, I swizzle this method and check whether I'm using `http` or `https` based on the `path` so you can choose based on `method`